# How to fine tune the style of IntervalMarkers -> "Bands"?

Tags: plotting, style

In Mathematica 12 I can use `ListPlot` to visualize uncertainty of tabulated data as bands. For example:

```
ListPlot[
    Table[{i, Around[Sin[i], 0.1 + 0.1 Cos[i]]}, {i, 0, 10, 1.0}],
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red],
    IntervalMarkers -> "Bands",
    IntervalMarkersStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed],
    Joined -> True,
    InterpolationOrder -> 3]
```

[image]

How can I control the filling color separately from the style of band border lines?

For example, I would like to make the dashed lines magenta, while keeping the band orange.

Another example: make dashed lines actually invisible (not just of the same color), but keep semi-transparent orange band. This is useful to visualize overlapping semi-transparent bands.

`IntervalMarkersStyle` has structured styling options, but they do not seem to work with `IntervalMarkers -> "Bands"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `"Bands"`, you can use `FaceForm` to style fillings. So, using

```
IntervalMarkersStyle -> Directive[Magenta,Thick, Dashed, FaceForm[Opacity[.3, Green]]]
```

we get

[image]

**Update:** To make the edges transparent, you can use

```
 IntervalMarkersStyle -> Directive["LineOpacity" -> 0, FaceForm[Opacity[.3, Green]]]
```

[image]

Additional undocumented directives that you can combine:

```
IntervalMarkersStyle -> Directive[
   "LineOpacity" -> .5,
   "LineColor" -> Blue,
   "Thickness" -> .01,
   "Dashing" -> Large,
   "FrontFaceColor" -> Yellow,
   "FrontFaceOpacity" -> .5 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The undocumented directives provide exactly the customizations I was looking for.